How To Set Initial Settings On netrw in Neovim?
I'm using neovim (v0.8.3) and like it quite well.  Recently discovered netrw and it's nice; I wanted to set some default settings for when the netrw pane opens but what I'm trying doesn't seem to work.
This is what I've added to my init.lua:
vim.o.netrw_winsize = 20
vim.o.netrw_banner = 0
vim.o.netrw_liststyle = 3

I close nvim and then reopen it and try :Lexplore and none of my changed settings seem to be respected.  That is, the netrw window looks no different--banner's still there and I'm not seeing the "tree" view.
My google fu is weak and a search here hasn't turned up anything.  Is this an issue with using neovim vs vim?  Should I be using a different setting?  Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

And inevitably a second after I post my question, I find the information I couldn't find prior.  I'll post it as an answer just in case anyone else runs across my question.

The netrw settings need to be set as global settings.  Hence instead of vim.o use vim.g:
vim.g.netrw_winsize = 20
vim.g.netrw_banner = 0
vim.g.netrw_liststyle = 3

